# Docker: i want a "personal" ip for containers

Tags: docker

Simple question: under KVM, I use a scheme like this

```
SERVER1(slackware with libvirt and kvm) 192.167.0.14 
interface BR0(bridged network to eth0)
```

the virtual machines of KVM take IP-addresses statically or or using dhcp on the same network (192.167.0.0/25)
I want to do something similar with docker.
For example

```
KVM: virtualmachine1 static ip 192.167.0.15
KVM: virtualmachine2 dynamic ip 192.167.0.22
```

I want to have

```
docker container1 static ip 192.167.0.15
docker container2 dynamic ip 192.167.0.22
```

i have tried many documents, but have had no success. The br0 interface that Docker containers take duplicates existing IP-addresses from my network.

Comment: The IP block 192.167.0.0/24 has been assigned to the Italian [National Institute for Nuclear Physics (INFN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istituto_Nazionale_di_Fisica_Nucleare). *Please* use one of the reserved [private address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) instead. [There are enough polluted IP spaces as it is…](http://www.potaroo.net/studies/1slash8/1slash8.html)

Comment: I use only this as example,is not my real ip,i not use it ,thanks for the warning

Comment: In that case, use the example.com ip blocks. 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24, 203.0.113.0/24  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found [here](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#macvlan)

supposing to use 10.1.1.133/24 and 10.1.1.1 as gateway

on host i did

```
ip addr del 10.1.1.133/24 dev eth0
ip link add link eth0 dev eth0m type macvlan mode bridge
ip link set eth0m up
ip addr add 10.1.1.133/24 dev eth0m
route add default gw 10.1.1.1
```

On container i did

```
CID=$(docker run -d ...)
pipework eth0 $CID 10.1.1.133/24@10.1.1.1
```